# Rails: How much work should a single migration do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coding-style, rails-migrations

I have to add foreign keys to several different tables in our Rails app. Is it better for me to add all the keys in one migration or to make several single-purpose migrations, one for each table being altered?

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, "several single-purpose migrations" is better. Make sure your migration run up AND down. On a side note, your migration filename should be descriptive enough for a 3rd party to understand what the migration does.

Answer (score 0):

When I do migrations I group changes based on common purpose. For instance if there are 3 changes that are for one feature of my app and 2 for another, I'll migrate those 3 together and then those 2 as another migration. That way in the future if I need to do a rollback, I'm only rolling back the changes that pertain to the area I'm working on.

Comment: I used to like the idea of doing that. But the problem is if one of the statements fail, and you fix it, then try to re-run the migration, the migration will be in a fail state where it can't run again because the first step was already completed

Comment: yeah, thats true, I do run into that from time to time.

Comment: So I ran into this at work where it made sense to drop about 8 columns in a single migration. Myself and a co-worker spoke about it, and migrations should be about a specific task. So to solve the problem i spoke of earlier, we wrapped all the statements in a transaction. `ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do`.

Answer (score 0):

I think, splitting the migrations or not is a question of what makes your code more clear. If adding multiple foreign keys is intended to be one task so do it in one migration. If your foreign keys come along with significant changes to the related models/controllers/views, it might be more clear to split them, so you can keep track of which migration belongs to which changes in the rest of your application.

When you are using git (or something similar), it might be helpful to bind corresponding changes in one commit.

From a performance point of view, it doesn't make a difference.